# ¿Es posible configurar Apache para desplegar sitios ssl y no ssl?

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

La duda que tengo es como configurar un servidor Apache para desplegar varios sitios, unos con certificado ssl y otros sin certificado ssl.

Digamos que tengo los siguientes sitios: dominio1.com, dominio2.com y dominio3.com. La situación sería la siguiente: el sito dominio2.com va a implementar un certificado ssl, pero los dominios 1 y 3 no.

Cúal sería la mejor práctica para que apache pueda desplegar los sitios en esas condiciones y que al navegar a https://dominio1.com no tome el certificado del domino 2?

Comment: configurar varios sitios se requieren un virtualhost por cada uno de ellos, cada uno de ellos se le instala el ssl tu decides cual puede entrar por https o no

Comment: Así lo he intentado. Estoy usando la directiva NameVirtualHost y he creado cada virtual host. Pero los que dejó sin ssl toman el ssl del que tiene el ssl.
Cómo puedo hacer para evitar esto?

Comment: no , crea dos virtualhost en /etc/apache/site-available/  luego reinicias apache

Comment: Hola Leonardo, te sugiero revisar [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad

Comment: Puedes leer este [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-configurar-virtual-hosts-de-apache-en-ubuntu-16-04-es), intentalo y si tienes un problema puntual crea una pregunta de acuerdo a las normas del sitio, con gusto te ayudaremos